# Rotating an object in a 3d scene

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, qt3d

Okay, I was trying to rotate an object in 3d and whenever we see an object rotating in 3d, it is not the object which is rotating. It is the camera which rotates and gives us the desired effect.

Now, say, I have two objects in the scene, one should be static and the other should be rotating. We have a main camera for the scene and a secondary camera which rotates around the second object.

My question is how does the main camera capture a scene where one object is constant and the other is rotating. Because, essentially it's the secondary camera which is rotating.

Shouldn't the main camera capture a scene wherein both the objects are static and the secondary camera is rotating?

Comment: That is not correct. Camera does not have to rotate. You can apply transformation on your object only and keep the camera still.

Comment: yes, that can be done too. But, I think there are situations where the camera rotates and not the object. My qustion concerns those cases.

Comment: For those cases this becomes very complicated. Rotating the camera means transforming the entire scene (from the camera's perspective). This means that if you want one object to be excluded from this 'explicit global scene transformation' you have to compute and apply an inverted transformation to that object, which is much more complicated (and unnatural) than just having a steady camera and transformable objects. If you are dealing with scene-graph concept, you can attach your non-movable object to rotating camera node - this will make it look still from camera view.

Comment: you can use layer masks so certain gameobjects cannot be seen by certain cameras in the scene... how you would combine that to produce a sensible image as described is beyond me at the moment. It's usually used so the GUI is static on screen whilst the objects within the scene move homogeneously.

Comment: thanks you archie and lefty. The scene graph concept is understandable